# ros2 rclpy.spin_once() in thread produce "generation already executing" exception

Tags: python-3.6, ros2

There is a requirement in my project where I have class in which I am creating  ros2 node (using rclpy) I have to create a publisher and subscriber which subscribe to specific  topic ,but I have to publish msg to the topic based on the recieved msg in the callback.
     I need to use th above object in other part of the project.
**As rclpy.spin() will block the process I tried to run it in a thread ,but I am getting "generator already executing" runtime exception.**

Can you please tell me how to resolve this  issue or what is the alternate solution for my usecase